# Getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when converting doc file to txt using apache POI

Tags: apache, text, apache-poi, indexoutofboundsexception, doc

I am using apache poi utility (poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar and related 3.9 version of POI jars) to convert doc file to txt.it is working with most of the files but I am getting an exception like as below

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 not accessible in a list of length 0
at org.apache.poi.util.IntList.get(IntList.java:346)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockAllocationTableReader.fetchBlocks(BlockAllocationTableReader.java:224)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockListImpl.fetchBlocks(BlockListImpl.java:123)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.SmallDocumentBlockList.fetchBlocks(SmallDocumentBlockList.java:30)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.processProperties(POIFSFileSystem.java:521)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:174)
```

The Code is following

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

// A HWPFDocument used to read document file from FileInputStream
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fileInputStream);

// A WordExtractor used to read textual content from document
WordExtractor docExtractor = new WordExtractor(doc);

// This Array stores each line from the document file.
String[] docArray = docExtractor.getParagraphText();
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < docArray.length; i++) {
    if (docArray[i] != null) {
        contents.append(docArray[i]);
        contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
}
isConverted = FileDirectoryOperations.writeTextOutputFile(targetFilePath, contents.toString());
```

we are getting exception at line `HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fileInputStream);`

do we have any fix for this.

please share your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Sourabh

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're getting indicates that there's something up with the way the underlying OLE2 container is structured.

The older `POIFSFileSystem` is a bit more picky than the newer (but read-only) `NPOIFSFileSystem` when it comes to the OLE2 structure, so you should probably try switching to that. Your setup code would then be:

```
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(file);
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs.getRoot());
WordExtractor docExtractor = new WordExtractor(doc);
```

As a bonus, NPOIFSFileSystem is also slightly faster and lower memory

Comment: yes , this is working now... can we use NPOIFSFileSystem for XWPFDocument (for docx) too.?

Comment: No, NPOIFS/POISF are only for the older OLE2 based documents like .doc. For the OOXML ones like .docx, you need to use OPCPackage as per all the documentation